# Radeon r7 250x does not work in motherboard, but a 7970 does.

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, amd-radeon

Motherboard in question: Intel dp45sg.

Used to be mine but I replaced it and am using it to build a second computer.  Got a new graphics card for this second computer, which is a r7 250x.

I know the 250x works as I tested it in my new computer, but the second computer, with the Intel board, refuses to even boot with it.  (everything turns on, but display remains blank)

The second computer with the Intel board still works just fine if I put my 7970 back in it.

**So my question is**: what did I fail to see as a difference between these two cards that would make the r7 250x incompatible with the Intel dp45sg.

As far as I can tell, it should work.  So I'm hesitant to pick a new one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the motherboard is really compatible with the graphics card.
   Contact the motherboard manufacturer if needed.
2. Check your BIOS options, try settings the BIOS to it's defaults.
3. Check if the problem is really the video card, try removing RAM modules, HD, etc. And check if it works without them.
4. You may need a BIOS update for the motherboard to work with the new graphics card.